# function with integer parameters

Tags: c, gmp

I have for example a function as follows:

```
int func(int a, int b, int c){...}
```

Now I want to use the GMP library. So how do I have to change the above code? Maybe something like:

```
int func(mpz_t a, mpz_t b, mpz_t c){...}
```

Comment: Firstly, add `#include <gmp/gmp.h>` before the first line...

Comment: @H2CO3 yes I know that, but that is not important for me right now.

Comment: mpz_t is a pointer to the internals of the GMP integer data structure, you need to use the functions available in the library to handle the data....

Comment: @sciarp could you give an example so I can understand?

Comment: I would suggest starting by reading the documentation.

Comment: It would be easier if you use the C++-Interface (`mpz_class` in `gmpxx.h`) since this has implemented operator overloading.

Comment: @H2CO3 It is just #include <gmp.h>, there is no gmp/gmp.h (or if there is, some "helpful" person added it for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at different function types here , and check the sample code for writing a function in GMP library. I hope this answers you question :-

http://gmplib.org/manual/

and also check this link for low level functions:-

http://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html#Low_002dlevel-Functions